# I get weird exception when retrieve image from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, illegalstateexception

Here is what I did:

I created an column (blob type) and saved successfully the byte array into it. Then I got the image by this code:

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    theme = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Theme"));  
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(theme, 0, theme.length);
    screenBackGround.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
```

- NOTE: There is just 1 row.

At 1st try:

- I used an 500x500 (12.6KB) image and it worked.

Then 2nd try:

- I used an 768x1280 (120KB) image and then I got this error:

  12-24 06:24:54.965: E/CursorWindow(1186): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 3 columns.

  12-24 06:24:54.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1186): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

I don't know why I get this exception, I thought there should be OutOfMemory exception or sth, please explain to me and teach me how to fix that. Thank you!

Comment: did image get added added to database properly in second case??

Comment: yes it was added properly

Comment: add your query because you get nothing check rows 0

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this message because for some reason your cursor contains 0 rows.
Modify your code something like this :

```
  if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
    theme = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Theme"));  
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(theme, 0, theme.length);
    screenBackGround.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
    }
```

cursor.moveToFirst() will return false if 0 rows returned, else it will point to the first record.